# Trouble having function minimization with constraints using Matlab as it returns the same value despite significant changes in function values

Tags: matlab, function, minimization

I am trying to minimize a function shown below as fun(a), and for different calculated values of Gf_delta(1,2,...7) values, it returns a specific set of values of 'a', which doesn't change with change in Gf_delta values.

[An image attached as link here to help understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCw6b.jpg)

```
a0 = [1,1,1,1,1,0.5,1];
fun = @(a) Gf_delta1*a(1)+Gf_delta2*a(2)+Gf_delta3*a(3)+Gf_delta4*a(4)+Gf_delta5*a(5)+Gf_delta6*a(6)+Gf_delta7*a(7)
A = []
B = []
Aeq = [1 2 1 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 2 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 2 2 0; 2 0 0 0 0 1 0]
Beq = [2,1,4,2]
lb = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ub = []
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp-legacy','MaxIterations',1500)
a = fmincon(fun,a0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,[],options)
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. When trying to reproduce your problem, I got different results for different values of `Gf_delta`. See the following copy pasted command line output:

```
>> Gf_delta = 1:7;
>> fun = @(a) Gf_delta*a.';
>> a = fmincon(fun,a0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,[],options)
a =

    1.0000    0.5000         0    0.2500    2.0000    0.0000         0

>> Gf_delta = -3:3;
>> fun = @(a) Gf_delta*a.';
>> a = fmincon(fun,a0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,[],options)
a =

    1.0000    0.2284    0.5433    0.3858    2.0000         0         0
```

Note, that I replaced the single values of `Gf_delta` by a vector, which simplifies `fun` to a vector-vector multiplication (but does not change the underlying problem). So the cause of same optimizaiton results lies somewhere else.

Some hints, where the cause may lie:

1. Note, that MATLAB stores the values of variables passed to anonmyous functions during the declaration. So changing the `Gf_delta` values requires to create `fun` again (as in the console output above). The [help page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) provide the example, where an anonymous function is created and parameters are deleted thereafer.
2. Maybe, your `Gf_delta` variable change only slightly or in a linear dependent manner, such that the solution of this Linear Programming problem really stays the same.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you so much for your immediate response. However, whenever I am changing the Gf_delta values, I re-run the code and that calculates again different values of Gf_delta (at those given conditions). So I think that changes my Gf_delta values every time. If my one set of Gf_delta values are - -4.1377, 0.1503, -0.2634, -3.2725, -3.5013, -7.4676, -5.6249. and my other set of calculated Gf_delta values are -6.2994,-1.0775, -0.0980, -0.3128, -0.3408, -4.4681, -2.4701 (which I think is a variation enough in Gf_delta values). Let me know if there's anything else I can do to figure out

Comment: a0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];  
    A = []  
    B = []  
    lb = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  
    ub = []  
    Aeq = [1 2 0 0 0 0 1; 0 1 2 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 2 2 0 0; 2 0 0 0 1 0 0]   
    Beq = [2,1,2,1]  
    options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp-legacy','MaxIterations',1500)  

    Gf_delta = 1:7;  
    fun = @(a) Gf_delta*a.';  
    a = fmincon(fun,a0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,[],options)  

    Gf_delta = -3:3;  
    fun = @(a) Gf_delta*a.';  
    a = fmincon(fun,a0,A,B,Aeq,Beq,lb,ub,[],options)

Comment: and the above attempt in comment section, still gives me the repeated output of a = [0.5000  0.7500   0.1250   1.0000    0    0.0000    0] , twice for Gf_delta = 1:7 and for Gf_delta = -3:3

Comment: I am not sure, what the question is now. Where the values of `Gf_delta` come from was not specified yet, or was it? So it will be hard to say, why your code outputs different values for `Gf_delta` without knowing, what it is about.

Comment: The second part (where `Beq` was modified to `[2 1 2 1 ]` compared to your original quesiton) yields the same results. This is, because the numbers, which are better for the minimizaiton problems are the first ones (because you have an increasing vector). At the same time, the equality conditions have to be fullfilled (for all values >0 in `a`). This results in the same solution now. If you try e.g. `Gf_delta=3:-1:-3`, then you will get another solution vector.

Comment: Alright. the changed values of Beq = [2 1 4 2] does give me different version of set of 'a' values. thanks.      But changing the values of Beq to [2 1 4 2] isn't making these changes to the original code output. The Gf_delta values are  actually calculated using different equations as per each value's requirement.

Comment: Hi Chris, can I have your email address to send you full version of code, and I guess that way you can have a look at the type fo Gf_delta values that I have

Comment: or if I give you two different sets of actual calculated values of Gf_delta, can you see why these values don't work -              Gf_delta = [-4.1377, 0.1503, -0.2634, -3.2725, -3.5013, -7.4676, -5.6249 ]            and my other set of calculated values are       Gf_delta = [-6.2994,-1.0775, -0.0980, -0.3128, -0.3408, -4.4681, -2.4701 ]         -using the same constraints for function minimization as above.

Comment: Those values seem to work for me: MATLAB returns `a =[0.0000         0         0    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000    2.0000]` for the first case and `a = [0.5000    0.0000         0    1.0000         0    1.0000    1.5000]` for the second. What exactly do you mean, that it does not work?

Comment: I don't get these values of a. For both of the set of Gf_delta values I gave you, my a = [ 0.0000         0    2.0000    0.0000    0.0000    2.0000    1.0000] and doesn't change. Can you please send me the optimization code that you wrote and it worked for you? I would highly appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Also does the version of matlab matter? I am using R2018b.

Comment: This code ( https://ideone.com/jXnhb7 ) gives me the results above. The MATLAB version should not have an influence. You can also try it on https://matlab.mathworks.com/ online to verify the results. But this seems to be a problem with your implementaiton or the MATLAB installation.

Comment: Hi Chris, that works, thank you so much for your constant assistance. I figured out why MATLAB gave same answers on different values of Gf_delta is that the precision of MATLAB is not high enough and gives up to 4 significant digits after decimal, where as this did not happen with when I used a Python code. I am yet to figure out how I can get more digits after decimal in the output, and in meanwhile< I can get my work done using a Python code. But, thanks, again...

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. In fact, MATLAB has at least the same precision as Python. If you directly use the calculated values for `Gf_delta` as variables instead of copy-pasting (which I am assuming you are doing), MATLAB uses full precision. You will also see more digits, when looking up the variable in the "variable explorer" (so you could copy-paste from there). The rounding to 4 digits is for displaying of variables only. You can try by `['[' sprintf('%.32d ', Gf_delta) ']']` with 32 significant digits. But the best option would be to directly use the variable of the calculated `Gf_delta`.